# How can I fast outer-join and filter two vectors (or lists), preferably in base R?

Tags: r

```
## outer join and filter
outer_join <- function(x, y, FUN) {
  if (missing(y)) {y = x}
  cp <- list()
  for (d1 in x) {
    for (d2 in  y) {
      if ( missing(FUN) || FUN(d1, d2) ) {
            cp <- c( cp, list(c(d1, d2)))       # and collect
       }
    }
  }
  return(cp)
}

## benchmark
system.time(t4 <- outer_join(seq(1e4), FUN=function(a,b){return( a == b)}) )
##  user  system elapsed
## 49.48    0.18   49.80

## examples
system.time(outer_join(seq(2^8))                                                   )  # cartesian product
system.time(outer_join(seq(2^8), FUN=function(a,b){return( a == b)} )              )  # all equal pairs
system.time(outer_join(seq(2^8), FUN=function(a,b,n=7){return( ((a-b) %% n) == 0)}))  # difference is 0 modulo 7
```

However above method is not suitable for larger datasets (> 1000).
Clearly, the nested for loop suggests room for improvement.
What is the best practice to do this in R?

Note that the ideal solution works when the expand.grid does not fit in memory (before filtering) but the resulting output does.  It is outer-join and filter instantaneously.

Comment: Another idea is to combine one element of x with all elements of y, and keep the required items. Perform this operation over all elements of x.

Comment: Or to use ?apply() to avoid the for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason your solution is so slow is because of the line `cp <- c( cp, list(c(d1, d2)))`. This is a very inefficient way to grow an object because it results in the object being copied with each `c()` call.

If you instead insert into a list you will see substantially better performance. We can make a couple of other small optimisations:

- Checking whether `FUN` is missing *outside* of the main loop so that we just need to do it once.
- Allocating a vector of the correct length up-front if `FUN` is missing, since we know the length of the output for this case.

```r
outer_join <- function(x, y = x, FUN) {
  fmissing <- missing(FUN)
  if (fmissing) {
    cp <- vector("list", length(x) * length(y))
  } else {
    cp <- list()
  }
  i <- 1L
  for (d1 in x) {
    for (d2 in y) {
      if (fmissing || FUN(d1, d2)) {
        cp[[i]] <- c(d1, d2)
        i <- i + 1L
      }
    }
  }
  cp
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  `Ex. 1` = outer_join(seq(2^8)),
  `Ex. 2` = outer_join(seq(2^8), FUN = `==`),
  `Ex. 3` = outer_join(seq(2^8), FUN = function(a, b) (a - b) %% 7L == 0),
  times = 10,
  unit = "s"
)
#> Unit: seconds
#>   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#>  Ex. 1 0.02300627 0.02473937 0.02787098 0.02566033 0.03057122 0.03753821    10
#>  Ex. 2 0.01391696 0.01527710 0.01785506 0.01735052 0.01916601 0.02490142    10
#>  Ex. 3 0.05839193 0.06460381 0.07189763 0.07218238 0.08215803 0.08275439    10
```

Also see [this chapter](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html#avoid-copies) from Hadley Wickham's Advanced R for a discussion of issues with growing objects, as well as Chapter 2 of [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). My experience is that R is not as slow at loops as it is reputed to be, as long as you avoid growing objects inefficiently.

Comment: That was very useful indeed. If Filter is missing then a solution without loops is possible as follows: if (missing(FUN)) {     cv <- rbind(rep(x, each = length(y)), y)     return(split(cv, rep(1:ncol(cv), each = nrow(cv))))   } else {    cp <- list(); ...

Comment: Note that `cp[[i]] <- c(d1, d2)` can be replaced by `cp[[length(cp) + 1]] <- c(d1,d2)` which renders the loop variable i redundant.

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve it with `expand.grid` + `subset`:

```r
outer_join <- function(x, y, FUN = `==`) {
  if (missing(y)) {y = x}
  subset(expand.grid(x = x, y = y), FUN(x, y))
}
```

###### Test

```r
system.time(res1 <- outer_join(seq(2^8)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.005   0.001   0.005

system.time(res2 <- outer_join(seq(2^8), FUN = function(a, b){ return( a == b) }))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.003   0.000   0.004

system.time(res3 <- outer_join(seq(2^8), FUN = function(a, b, n = 7){ return( ((a-b) %% n) == 0) }))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.007   0.001   0.007

all.equal(res1, res2)
# [1] TRUE

res3
#        x  y
# 1      1  1
# 8      8  1
# 15    15  1
# 22    22  1
# 29    29  1
# 36    36  1
# etc.
```

Comment: Note however that the above solution does not work if the product does not fit in memory and the resulting output does. It is outer-join and filter instantaneously.

`system.time(robj <- outer_join(seq(2^16), FUN=function(a,b,n=2^16-1){return((a-b) == n) }))`

Comment: @clp To outer-join and filter instantaneously, a nested loops are indeed needed, but not loops in R. You could adapt your R loops for a C++ version and compile it into R with `rcpp`.

Comment: I could also resort to some form of sql.

Answer (score 2):

If your `FUN` is something that can be [translated](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation-function.html) to sql by dbplyr, you could use duckdb + dbplyr and supply `FUN` as an expression rather than an actual function. This

```r
library(duckdb)
#> Loading required package: DBI
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(dbplyr, warn = FALSE)

outer_join <- function(x, y, FUN, show_query = FALSE){
  if (missing(y)) y <- x
  con <- dbConnect(duckdb(), dbdir = ':memory:')
  dbWriteTable(con, 'x', tibble(x))
  dbWriteTable(con, 'y', tibble(y))
  x_tbl <- tbl(con, 'x')
  y_tbl <- tbl(con, 'y')
  out <- 
    x_tbl %>% 
      inner_join(y_tbl, sql_on = '1 = 1') %>% 
      filter({{ FUN }}) %>% 
      {if (show_query) show_query(.) else .} %>% 
      collect
  dbDisconnect(con)
  out
}
```

Example:

```
outer_join(seq(2^8), FUN = x == y, show_query = TRUE)
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT *
#> FROM (
#>   SELECT "x", "y"
#>   FROM "x" AS "LHS"
#>   INNER JOIN "y" AS "RHS"
#>     ON (1 = 1)
#> ) "q01"
#> WHERE ("x" = "y")
#> # A tibble: 256 × 2
#>        x     y
#>    <int> <int>
#>  1     1     1
#>  2     2     2
#>  3     3     3
#>  4     4     4
#>  5     5     5
#>  6     6     6
#>  7     7     7
#>  8     8     8
#>  9     9     9
#> 10    10    10
#> # … with 246 more rows
```

Benchmark (note the memory allocation):

```
expand_oj <- function(x, y, FUN = `==`) {
  if (missing(y)) {y = x}
  subset(expand.grid(x = x, y = y), FUN(x, y))
}

x <- seq(2^8)
bench::mark(
  duck = outer_join(x, FUN = x == y),
  expand = expand_oj(x, FUN = `==`),
  check = function(a, b) all(a == b)
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 duck        53.31ms  57.79ms      17.3  266.34KB     21.1
#> 2 expand       1.22ms   1.55ms     461.     3.08MB     29.9

x <- seq(2^13)
bench::mark(
  duck = outer_join(x, FUN = x == y),
  expand = expand_oj(x, FUN = `==`),
  check = function(a, b) all(a == b)
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 duck        50.69ms  53.34ms    18.2       359KB     5.46
#> 2 expand        1.44s    1.44s     0.693       3GB     2.77
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or use {sqldf}

```r
library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite

use_sqldf <- function(x, y = x) {
  df_x <- data.frame(x)
  df_y <- data.frame(y)
  
  sqldf('
  select
    *
  from
    df_x join df_y on 1 = 1
  where
    x = y
  ')
}

x <- seq(2^13)
bench::mark(
  duck = outer_join(x, FUN = x == y),
  expand = expand_oj(x, FUN = `==`),
  use_sqldf = use_sqldf(x),
  check = function(a, b) all(a == b)
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 duck        74.16ms  76.79ms    12.6    381.86KB     3.59
#> 2 expand        1.43s    1.43s     0.702       3GB     2.81
#> 3 use_sqldf   36.01ms  37.93ms    24.0      1.69MB     2.00
```

Comment: This is much more cumbersome then in SAS.
In SAS it amounts to: 



`data robj;
  merge x, y;
  if filter then output(robj)

proc print(robj);
`

Answer (score 0):

The fasted solution I could find.
Genuine improvements, preferably in the R base, are welcome.

```
## cross join and filter.
cjf <- function(x, y = x, FUN, ...) {
  if (is.matrix(x)) return(NULL); if (is.matrix(y)) return(NULL)
  rrr <- c()
  fmissing <- missing(FUN)
  if (!fmissing && (length(FUN(x,x)) != length(x)) ) {
    warning("length(FUN(x,x)) do not match length(x)")
  }
  if (!fmissing) FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  for (i in seq_along(y) ) {
    if (fmissing) {
      mmm <- rbind(x, y[i])
    } else {
      idx      <- which(FUN(x, y[i]) ) # idx is possible empty
      if (length(idx) > 0) mmm  <- rbind(x[idx], y[i]) else mmm <- c()
    }
    rrr[length(rrr) + seq_along(mmm)] <- mmm
  }
  if (length(rrr) == 0) rrr <- matrix(0, nrow = 0, ncol = 0)
  return(matrix(rrr, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
}
## system.time(jjj <- cjf(seq(1e4), FUN = function(a, b) a>b & (a - b) %% 7L == 0) )
## expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
##   0) 1.777018 1.797532 1.806776 1.805949 1.813646 1.89837   100

## Examples.
f_gt <- function(a,b){return( a > b) }
x_1  <- cjf(letters[1:5])
x_2  <- cjf(0:1, letters[1:5]) 
x_3a <- cjf(0:1, letters[1:5],   FUN = function(a,b) a == a)  
x_3b <- cjf(0:1, letters[1:5],   FUN = function(a,b) rep(TRUE, length(a)))
x_3c <- cjf(0:1, letters[1:5],   FUN = function(a,b) a != a) 
x_3d <- cjf(0:1, letters[1:5],   FUN = function(a,b) rep(FALSE, length(a)))
x_3e <- cjf(1:2+1i, 0:5,         FUN = function(a,b) Mod(a) > Mod(b))
x_4a <- cjf(letters[1:5],        FUN = f_gt)
x_4b <- cjf(letters[1:5],        FUN = `>`)
x_4c <- cjf(letters[1:5],        FUN = function(a,b) a > b)
x_4d <- cjf(as.double(seq(1E4)), FUN = function(a,b){return( abs(a*a*a - b) <= .Machine$double.eps) } )
x_5  <- cjf(list("a", "b", "c"))
```